# Modifying intermediate gradients Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

You can get intermediate gradients with `tf.gradients()`and you can create a new tensor by applying an op on this results (like clipping) but how to modify the backpropagation accordingly ?

For instance to implement the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss) (with delta=1). 
The first method is to create a boolean mask on the batch dimension doing something like.

```
cond=tf.less(input_tensor,1)
cond=tf.cast(cond,"tf.float32")
loss=cond*tf.square(input_tensor)+(1.-cond)*(tf.abs(input_tensor)-0.5)
```

A simpler way to implement it would be to use the l2 loss and to clip its gradients wrt inputs to 1.

```
l2_loss=tf.square(input_tensor)
modified_grad_wrt_input=tf.clip_by_value(tf.gradients(l2_loss,input_tensor),0.,1.)
```

But when you train your network you have to use `compute_gradients` and `apply_gradients`, which only give you gradients wrt variables. How to make your optimizer use the tensor `modified_grad_wrt_input` when doing the chain rule ?

Do you have to use gradient_override_map as in this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1095) ?
Is there a simpler way without registering a new op/gradients ?

Comment: `gradient_override_map` is probably the simplest way

Comment: Ok ! I figured the same but I wanted to be sure I was not missing something obvious.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov - can you copy your comment to an answer?  Thanks!